# How to get data-attribute in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have this list:

```
    const chosen = (e: any) => console.log(e.target.dataset.value)

...
                <ul>
                  {numbers.map(n => (
                    <a data-value={n} onClick={chosen}>
                      <li key={n}>
                        {n}
                      </li>
                    </a>
                  ))}
                </ul>
...
```

It logs `undefined`.

Also tried this: `console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-value'))` and it returns `null`.

How do I get the value from `a` tag?

Stack: TypeScript: 3.8.3, React: 16.13.1

Comment: isn't it just `element.getAttribute(attributeName);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In frameworks like React and Vue you generally stay away from reading data from the DOM when possible. In this case, you can capture the value in a function:

```js
    const chosen = (e: any, value: any) => console.log(value)

...
                <ul>
                  {numbers.map(n => (
                    <a key={n} onClick={(event) => { chosen(event, n); }}>
                      <li>
                        {n}
                      </li>
                    </a>
                  ))}
                </ul>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to do that:

```
export default function App() {
  function chosen(event) {
    const meta = event.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-value");
    console.log(meta);
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {numbers.map((n) => (
        <a data-value={n} onClick={chosen}>
          <li key={n}>{n}</li>
        </a>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`li` element should contentin the `a` element. Please try this example

```
import React from "react";

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function App() {
  function chosen(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(event.target.dataset.value);
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {numbers.map((number) => {
        return (
          <li key={number}>
            <a href="!#" onClick={chosen} data-value={number}>
              {number}
            </a>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And follow the Ross Allen advice

Answer (score 0):

Access attributes from the `currentTarget` instead like this :

`console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-value'))`